# How to create a while loop for Http get request to keep repeating the process till some value is true? in Kotlin

Tags: android, http, kotlin

I want to make an Http get request. I have an API that returns JSON as the response. This json has a key can_load, whose value is true if there are more items to be loaded and it requires page number to keep loading a set of items. The first time I give the page number as 1 and then I want the page no. to keep incrementing by 1 till the time the can_load value is true. I have tried creating a func. body in which the whole process happens and then a while loop which calls the fun after incrementing the pageNum but I am not getting any result. without the fun and while loop I get the first set of items in pageNum 1.
I want to increment the pageNum to 2 and so on till the value is true. Oncw boolean vaalue is false it should stop.

```
   var canload: Boolean

    var pageNum = 1

    fun loadItems() {

    if(status == "1") {



        Log.v("statusUserId", userId!!)


        val httpClient4 = AsyncHttpClient()


            httpClient4.get("https://somesite.com/services/ajax_v6.7.aspx?app=android&ver=6.59&lang=en&countryId=1&cat=getItem&userId=$userId&pageNum=$pageNum&&occasionLink=", object : AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


                override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>?, responseBody: ByteArray?) {

                    if (responseBody != null) {


                            val charset4 = Charsets.UTF_8

                            val json4 = String(responseBody, charset4)

                            val gson4 = Gson().newBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

                            val itemscreenresult = gson4.fromJson<Json4>(json4, genericType<Json4>())

                            jsonInfo6.addAll(itemscreenresult.result.data)

                            Log.v("json4", json4)
                            Log.v("Itemscreenresult", itemscreenresult.toString())
                            Log.v("Jsoninfo6", jsonInfo6.toString())


                            canload = itemscreenresult.result.can_load
                            Log.v("homeresult userID", canload.toString())


                            itemscreenAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()


                            while(canload==true){
                                pageNum = pageNum + 1

                                loadItems()
                            }




                    }



                }

                override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>?, responseBody: ByteArray?, error: Throwable?) {
                    Log.v("Test", error?.message ?: "")
                }

            }  )
        }







    }
```

Comment: `while(canload==true)` Change to `if(canload==true)` Or yet better `if(canload)`

Comment: should the loop be written inside the response body itself?

Comment: Just make the change i proposed. You are not even reporting the effect.